# Does a selfdestruct affect child contracts?

Tags: selfdestruct

Say, I create a smart contract A and this contract creates another smart contract B. If I call `selfdestruct` on A, will this affect in any way contract B? Or can I still call functions on B after A is killed?

I found this example on Etherscan:

- Original contract A: https://etherscan.io/address/0x14fea711dca8fcea6be47e14ea1406384f18c7cc
- Contract B created by A: https://etherscan.io/address/0x02820e4bee488c40f7455fdca53125565148708f

Contract A is selfdestructed and therefore has no code anymore. B also has empty code, but it does not have the red SelfDestruct label on Etherscan. So did the SelfDestruct of A lead to a deletion of B's code or is this just coincidence and this contract B never had any code associated with it at all?

Answer (score 4):

No. `selfdestruct` of a contract does not effect any contracts created by the contract to be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source or maybe even a concrete example where this is the case?